# Chrome not reachable Selenium WebDriver error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing this issue; I know this question is already present and I have tried the solutions mentioned hence asking this with my configurations and code.

Earlier the scripts were running but now they aren't So i tried making a basic open browser script.

Latest Version of Selenium WebDriver : http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.5/selenium-java-3.5.0.zip

Latest Version on ChromeDriver : http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.31/

Basic Open browser code:

```
package Trial;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Trial_Class {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.youtube.com");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
}
```

But still I am getting the below error:

```
 Starting ChromeDriver 2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8) on port 43967
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 61.81 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'SWATI', ip: '192.168.0.5', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$24(ProtocolHandshake.java:360)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:641)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:254)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
    at Trial.Trial_Class.main(Trial_Class.java:11)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Update your Chrome browser version.

Answer (score 3):

Your chromedriver is starting just fine:

> "Starting ChromeDriver 2.31.488763
>   (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8) on port 43967"

The problem is the browser itself is not responding. So I have two ideas:

1) Your browser is not installed in the default location; If this is the case, add this to your code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/path/to/other/chrome/binary");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

2) Your browser is latest version, but your chromedriver isn't - current is 2.33

Answer (score 1):

I found that chromedriver had hard time to resolve localhost and during that it printed

```
Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
```

It first tried to connect via ipv6 and then I guess fall back to ipv4. So what worked for me was to change the priority of "localhosts" this way

> The only piece you should need to do is change the priority:
>
> Open RegEdit, navigate to
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\tcpip6\Parameters
>   Create DisabledComponents DWORD registry value, set its value to 20
>   (Hexadecimal). [src](https://serverfault.com/a/813430)

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the

```
setProperty(String key, String path)
```

here **"`key`"** is your "`webdriver.chrome.driver`" and **"`path`"** is "path where your driver is stored". Use single forward slash **"`/`"** in path.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.youtube.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Above code is work well in Selenium jar 3.5.0. Hope works fine in your system too.