# python selenium: WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing the issue with python selenium 
I entered the code below, it worked well few minutes ago, but now it doesn't work saying chrome not reachable
Please help!

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Danny/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

results

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-6bcc3a6d3d05> in <module>()
----> 1 driver.get('https://google.com')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in get(self, url)
    322         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    323         """
--> 324         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    325 
    326     @property

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    310         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    311         if response:
--> 312             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    313             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    314                 response.get('value', None))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=64.0.3282.140)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Edit

It does work when I try this code, but I don't know why it suddenly works
Can someone explain this code?

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users\Danny\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

for i in range(1,10):
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome not reachable Selenium WebDriver error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688020/chrome-not-reachable-selenium-webdriver-error)

Comment: I've recently had the same problem. My problem was that I didn't have chrome(automated) one open. So I've opened it an ran the code and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are seeing gives us some hint as follows :

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-6bcc3a6d3d05> in <module>()
----> 1 driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Here are some observations and remedies :

- First of all, I would like you to look back at the exact absolute path of the *ChromeDriver* binary and my guess is instead of :

  ```
  /Users/Users/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver
  ```

  It should have been :

  ```
  /Users/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver
  ```
- Moreover, a better way to pass the location of the *ChromeDriver* binary would be to pass the argument `executable_path` along as well, so the line would be :

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/Users/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver')
  ```
- Finally, whenever you invoke `get()` method to open an *URL* try to pass the [**Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) as follows :

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answers but it doesn't work. It shows same error as before :(

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
path=r"/Users/Users/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

That r in the path stands for "raw" and it might fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work...it shows same error :( When i run 'driver' code, it pops up new Chrome tab saying that data:,

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I have found that simply restarting my development machine solves this problem for me. It occasionally crops up with no particular explanation, and resolves with a reboot.