# R Scrape a list of Google + urls using purrr package

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, purrr, rselenium

I am working on a web scraping project, which aims to extract Google + reviews from a set of children's hospitals. My methodology is as follows:

**1)** Define a list of Google + urls to navigate to for review scraping. The urls are in a dataframe along with other variables defining the hospital.

**2)** Scrape reviews, number of stars, and post time for all reviews related to a given url.

**3)** Save these elements in a dataframe, and name the dataframe after another variable in the dataframe corresponding to the url.

**4)** Move on to the next url ... and so on till all urls are scraped.

Currently, the code is able to scrape from a single url. I have tried to create a function using  `map` from the `purrr` package. However it doesn't seem to be working, I am doing something wrong.

**Here is my attempt, with comments on the purpose of each step**

```
#Load the necessary libraries
devtools::install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(RSelenium)
#To avoid any SSL error messages
library(httr)
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
```

**Defining the URL dataframe**

```
#Now to define the dataframe with the urls
urls_df =data.frame(Name=c("CHKD","AIDHC")
                    ,ID=c("AAWZ12","AAWZ13")
                    ,GooglePlus_URL=c("https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=fJUKW9DcJuqSgAbPsZ3gDQ&q=Childrens+Hospital+of+the+Kings+Daughter+&oq=Childrens+Hospital+of+the+Kings+Daughter+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13k1j0i22i10i30k1j0i22i30k1l7.8445.8445.0.9118.1.1.0.0.0.0.144.144.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.143....0.qDMr7IDA-uA#lrd=0x89ba9869b87f1a69:0x384861b1e3a4efd3,1,,,",
                                      "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Alfred+I+DuPont+Hospital+for+Children&oq=Alfred+I+DuPont+Hospital+for+Children&aqs=chrome..69i57.341j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#lrd=0x89c6fce9425c92bd:0x80e502f2175fb19c,1,,,"
                                      ))
```

**Creating the function**

```
extract_google_review=function(googleplus_urls) {

  #Opens a Chrome session
  rmDr=rsDriver(browser = "chrome",check = F)
  myclient= rmDr$client

  #Creates a sub-dataframe for the filtered hospital, which I will later use to name the dataframe
  urls_df_sub=urls_df %>% filter(GooglePlus_URL %in% googleplus_urls)

  #Navigate to the url
  myclient$navigate(googleplus_urls)

  #click on the snippet to switch focus----------
  webEle <- myclient$findElement(using = "css",value = ".review-snippet")
  webEle$clickElement()
  # Save page source
  pagesource= myclient$getPageSource()[[1]]

  #simulate scroll down for several times-------------
  count=read_html(pagesource) %>%
    html_nodes(".p13zmc") %>%
    html_text()

  #Stores the number of reviews for the url, so we know how many times to scroll down
  scroll_down_times=count %>%
    str_sub(1,nchar(count)-5) %>%
    as.numeric()

  for(i in 1 :scroll_down_times){
    webEle$sendKeysToActiveElement(sendKeys = list(key="page_down"))
    #the content needs time to load,wait 1.2 second every 5 scroll downs
    if(i%%5==0){
      Sys.sleep(1.2)
    }
  }

  #loop and simulate clicking on all "click on more" elements-------------
  webEles <- myclient$findElements(using = "css",value = ".review-more-link")
  for(webEle in webEles){
    tryCatch(webEle$clickElement(),error=function(e){print(e)})
  }

  pagesource= myclient$getPageSource()[[1]]
  #this should get the full review, including translation and original text
    reviews=read_html(pagesource) %>%
    html_nodes(".review-full-text") %>%
    html_text()

  #number of stars
  stars <- read_html(pagesource) %>%
    html_node(".review-dialog-list") %>%
    html_nodes("g-review-stars > span") %>%
    html_attr("aria-label")

  #time posted
  post_time <- read_html(pagesource) %>%
    html_node(".review-dialog-list") %>%
    html_nodes(".dehysf") %>%
    html_text()

  #Consolidating everything into a dataframe
  reviews=head(reviews,min(length(reviews),length(stars),length(post_time)))
  stars=head(stars,min(length(reviews),length(stars),length(post_time))) 
  post_time=head(post_time,min(length(reviews),length(stars),length(post_time)))
  reviews_df=data.frame(review=reviews,rating=stars,time=post_time)

  #Assign the dataframe a name based on the value in column 'Name' of the dataframe urls_df, defined above
  df_name <- tolower(urls_df_sub$Name)

  if(exists(df_name)) {
    assign(df_name, unique(rbind(get(df_name), reviews_df)))
  } else {
    assign(df_name, reviews_df)
  }


} #End function
```

**Feeding the urls into the function**

```
#Now that the function is defined, it is time to create a vector of urls and feed this vector into the function
googleplus_urls=urls_df$GooglePlus_URL
googleplus_urls %>% map(extract_google_review)
```

There seems to be an error in the function ,which is preventing it from scraping and storing the data into separate dataframes like intended.

**My Intended Output**

> 2 dataframes, each with 3 columns

Any pointers on how this can be improved will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should better use for loop instead of map. Because you need to open additional windows for web-scraping using selenium. You can check selenium parallel scraping guide. Currently, I don't think there is a R version thouh.

Comment: Ok. So this is not possible for R at the moment?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950958/run-rselenium-in-parallel?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I think I'm wrong, it's possible to do it with other packages. The link above should work.

Comment: I tried using `foreach` like you suggested from the link above, but it still doesn't seem to be working

Comment: The error probably comes from the part where each dataframe is named based on the corresponding value in the `Name` column in `urls_df`

Comment: It could be. If all other methods don't work, you can still use for loop.

Comment: Hello Yifu Yan, I was looking to add another element to the dataframe scraping the reviews. I'd like to include the replies to a review posted (if any). Could you please help identify the html snippet that corresponds to this block? I tried right clicking and selecting 'Inspect', but I cannot find the right snippet. Thanks