# Error while web-scraping webdriver exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
!pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
errors = []
season = []

for id in range(46605, 46985):
my_url = f'https://www.premierleague.com/match/{id}'
option = Options()
#option.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get(my_url)
```

Code runs fine till here.

```
date = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/section/div[2]/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]'))).text
date = datetime.strptime(date, '%a %d %b %Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
home_team = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/section/div[2]/section/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a[2]/span[1]').text
away_team = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/section/div[2]/section/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/a[2]/span[1]').text
```

An error pops up while executing these lines.
[Error Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeZaw.png)

[Error Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8vEU.png)

Comment: I wouldn't put the selenium driver within the for loop- its pretty slow and will be running close to 400 times here. There's no reason to open and close the link that many times. Also, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688020/chrome-not-reachable-selenium-webdriver-error

Comment: Adding to the comment made by @Joe, I see you are using a lot of long xpaths, which is not a good practice. Try using narrowly relative xpaths, like this one for the first element (date):  `//div[@class='matchInfo']//div[contains(@class, 'matchDate')]`

Comment: @Joe  that is in Java, could you suggest a code for python?

Comment: @AnandGautam if possible could you please write the exact syntax I have no clue about it. I am sorry If it's a bother

Comment: I already gave you the date in my earlier comment. Just replace the xpath with mine, as it;s more relative.
This one's for home_team: `//div[@class='team home']`
This one's for away_team `//div[@class='team away']`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the api that the premierleague site uses?

```
import requests

fixture = 66553

headers =   {
    'accept':'*/*',
    'accept-encoding':"gzip;q=1.0, identity; q=0.5",
    'accept-language':'en-ZA,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,de;q=0.6',
    'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'origin':'https://www.premierleague.com',
    'referer':'https://www.premierleague.com/',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36'
    }

url = f'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/broadcasting-schedule/fixtures/{fixture}'
data = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()

print(data['fixture']['attendance'])
print(data['fixture']['kickoff']['label'])
print(data['fixture']['teams'])

url = f'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/fixtures/{fixture}/textstream/EN?pageSize=1000&sort=desc'
data = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()

for message in data['events']['content']:
    print(message['text'])
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kaustav, writing this in answer as the it's a code block, and do not know how to put it in comment section.
Although I second the thoughts of @Joe, since you wanted an exact syntax, I thought I could put together a block of code to show you.
So, this code here, opens the browser, gets the details (as you put in your code), and then stores them in a list (for display purpose for this task, but in practice it may not be required - depends on your requirement).

I would again reiterate that opening, using, and closing a browser (even a headless one) for so many iterations may hit the performance at some point in time in the loop, and all your time would go waste. I would strongly suggest you to find an API of this website if available and use it to success.

Having said that, here is the code for your use.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as p
import time
errors = []
season = []

url_ls=[] # used to show to query creator a demo
for id in range(46605, 46985):
    my_url = f'https://www.premierleague.com/match/{id}'
    option = Options()
    option.add_argument('--headless')
    option.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
    driver.get(my_url)
    title = driver.current_url
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Accept All Cookies']"))).click()
    except:
        print("cookie modal not found")
        continue
    # time.sleep(10)
    match_date = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='matchInfo']//div[contains(@class, 'matchDate')]"))).text
    match_date_f = datetime.strptime(match_date, '%a %d %b %Y').strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    home_team = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='team home']").text
    away_team = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='team away']").text
    tup = (title + "|" + match_date + "|" + home_team + "|" + away_team)
    url_ls.append(tup)
    driver.close()
print(url_ls)  # used to show to query creator a demo
```

Here is the output (I just appended the current url, and the texts of the elements in this code, but you can further expand this block and add your elements - and you can as you've imported pandas, send data to a dataframe and then to excel or csv - as you like it)

```
['https://www.premierleague.com/match/46605|Sat 10 Aug 2019|Liverpool|Norwich City', 'https://www.premierleague.com/match/46606|Sat 10 Aug 2019|AFC Bournemouth|Sheffield United', 'https://www.premierleague.com/match/46607|Sat 10 Aug 2019|Burnley|Southampton', 'https://www.premierleague.com/match/46608|Sat 10 Aug 2019|Crystal Palace|Everton', 'https://www.premierleague.com/match/46609|Sun 11 Aug 2019|Leicester City|Wolverhampton Wanderers']

Process finished with exit code 0
```